How do I force Wayland on in Linux when using Nvidia proprietary drivers?
I installed the Nvidia 555 proprietary drivers (which support Wayland) on Debian Trixie with the .sh installer from nvidia.com and when I try to login with Wayland, I do not get the option; the cog on the login screen does not show with Xorg which indicates that it only supports logging in with Xorg and Wayland is disabled, and of course when I login $XDG_SESSION_TYPE does not have the wayland value.
I tried setting WaylandEnable=true in /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf (aka /etc/gdm3/custom.conf for Ubuntu users) but that had no effect.
I know that GDM is wrong and I can use Wayland, but GDM refuses to let me use it.

This is a hack, but editing /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules (or /etc/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules) to comment out this line allows me to use Wayland on Debian Trixie with the Nvidia 555 proprietary driver.
94c94
< RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"
---
> #RUN+="/usr/libexec/gdm-runtime-config set daemon WaylandEnable false"


Oh GAM! I wish we didn't need to hack everything from Nvidia, in order to get our already paid for stuff, working.

As I understand, it does work with sufficiently new driver versions - the current 61-gdm.rules only disables wayland if nvidia-modeset is disabled or if the suspend/resume services are missing. Might have been different in Debian Trixie though.

It must be some other issue than nvidia-modeset being disabled because  $ sudo cat /sys/module/nvidia_drm/parameters/modeset returns Y
